# Sequelize Eager Load Error with hasMany on two models

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models (Course and Company) that are associated as foreign keys into a logging model. I'm able to include/join the Course model without issue in queries on the Log model, however the Company model always throws a Sequelize Eager Loading Error.

I've tried using 'as: companies' on the hasMany and belongsTo associations, but that hasn't worked. I've also tried reordering, with no success.

````
// The log model

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Log = sequelize.define("Log", {
    user: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    {...other values}
  })

  Log.associate = models => {
    models.Log.belongsTo(models.Company, {
      foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false
      }
    })
  }

  Log.associate = models => {
    models.Log.belongsTo(models.Course, {
      foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false
      }
    })
  }

  return Log
}


// the Course model

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Course = sequelize.define("Course", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    courseId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  })

  Course.associate = models => {
    models.Course.hasMany(models.Log)
  }

  return Course
}

// The Company model which does not work in a query:

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Company = sequelize.define("Company", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  })

  Company.associate = models => {
    models.Company.hasMany(models.Log)
  }

  return Company
}

// And finally the query, where swapping the include to be [db.Course] works, however db.Company does not:

db.Log.findAll({
  attributes: [
    "CompanyId",
  ],
  include: [db.Company]
})
.then(dbCompanies => {
  res.json(dbCompanies)
})
.catch(err => res.send(err));```

Including the course model brings in that data without any issue, but any time the company is used, it throws an error. They are identical, from what I can see.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is correct, but the syntax is off. A model's "associate" method gets called when the model is loaded. You are wanting to associate the "Log" model with both the "Company" and "Course" models, but you are defining "associate" twice, and like with all variables in JavaScript, only the last definition matters. Your original definition, which associates the "Log" and "Company" models, is overwritten, which is why you are getting the error above.

Instead, you can create one "associate" method that creates both associations:

```js
Log.associate = models => {
  models.Log.belongsTo(models.Company, {
    foreignKey: {
      allowNull: false
    }
  })

  models.Log.belongsTo(models.Course, {
    foreignKey: {
      allowNull: false
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: This solved it - simple as it seems. Sequelize doesn't have the most user-friendly documentation. Thanks!